# AMPPS: Using port 8080 for Apache, Wordpress admin accessible but homepage does not load

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, redirect, ampps

I have AMPPS installed on Windows 10. I'm using port 8080 for Apache. I installed Wordpress through AMPPS and I'm able to access the dashboard and other pages, just not the homepage.

Both siteurl and home are set to http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp in the database in phpmyadmin. The dashboard loads correctly at http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp/wp-admin/, and other pages like http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp/home/ load. But trying to load http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp/ redirects to http://localhost/wordpress/wp/ and results in a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside your config file;

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp');
```

This will force WordPress to use that.

Comment: What  is the value inside table `wp_options` column `option_value` ?

Comment: Can you edit your functions.php inside your theme folder, and add `remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');` for removing redirection. Because your wp-admin isn't redirecting I think it's inside your theme somewhere.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. I tried switching to a few different themes too and had the same issue with all of them.

Comment: What is your .htaccess?

Comment: Here's the full text of it:

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress